# Angular reactive form after click submit show "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addProductFromAdmin' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to create adding product form for my project. However, after I clicking submit button, my reactive form gives me this error.
[image: error] It seem like something is undefined when I call my service API, but I couldn't figure it out for three hours. Maybe is the file in the addProductForm??

Component

```
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {NgbAlert} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {Product} from '../product';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-modify-add-product',
  templateUrl: './admin-modify-add-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-modify-add-product.component.css']
})
export class AdminModifyAddProductComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() countChanged: EventEmitter<number> =   new EventEmitter();

  admin_id:string;
  url:string;
  addProductForm: FormGroup;
  submitted:boolean=false;
  file:File=null;
  productService:ProductService;
  private _success = new Subject<string>();  
  @ViewChild('selfClosingAlert', {static: false}) selfClosingAlert: NgbAlert;
  successMessage = '';
  product:Product;
  Condition:any=['new','used','unknow']
  Category:any=['electronic','apparel','food']


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _location: Location,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getId();
    this.createForm();
    this._success.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.selfClosingAlert) {
        this.selfClosingAlert.close();
      }
    });
  }

  getId(){
    this.admin_id=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

  }

  backClicked() {
    this._location.back();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.addProductForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      product_name:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1)]],
      product_quantity:['',[Validators.required,Validators.min(1)]],
      product_price:['',[Validators.required,Validators.min(1)]],
      product_image:[null,[Validators.required]],
      product_category:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1)]],
      product_condition:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1)]],
    });
    // this.addProductForm=new FormGroup({
    //   product_name: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1)]),
    //   product_quantity:new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.min(0)]),
    //   product_price:new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.min(0)]),
    //   product_image:new FormControl(['',Validators.required]),
    //   product_category:new FormControl(['',Validators.required]),
    //   product_condition:new FormControl(['',Validators.required])
    // });

  }

  get f(){
    return this.addProductForm.controls;
  }

  onFileChange(event:any) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.addProductForm.patchValue({
          product_image: reader.result
        });
        
      };
    }

  }

   
  changeSuccessMessage() {
    this.successMessage="Product Success Added!";
  }


  onSubmit(){
    console.log("onSumbit yes");
    this.submitted=true;

    console.log("invalide? "+this.addProductForm.invalid);



    console.log("name "+ this.addProductForm.value.product_name);
    console.log("qu "+ this.addProductForm.value.product_quantity);
    console.log("pr "+ this.addProductForm.value.product_price);
    console.log("ca "+ this.addProductForm.value.product_category);
    console.log("co "+ this.addProductForm.value.product_condition);
    console.log("img "+ this.f['product_image'].value);
    console.log("-----------------");
    console.log("id "+this.admin_id);

    if (this.addProductForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("productForm "+this.addProductForm.value);

      this.productService.addProductFromAdmin(this.admin_id, this.addProductForm.value).subscribe(
        res=>{
          console.log(res);
          alert('Updated Successfully.')
          this.changeSuccessMessage();
          this.backClicked();
        }

      );
    
       this.onReset();
  }



  onReset() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.addProductForm.reset();
  }





  

}
```

template

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="back_icon">
        <span (click)="backClicked()">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H5.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L5.707 7.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <h2 style="text-decoration: none;">Add New Product</h2>

        <form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="from-group">
                <label for="product_name">Product Name:</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="product_name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_name.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_name.errors.required">Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="from-group ">
                <label for="product_quantity">Product Quantity:</label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="product_quantity" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_quantity.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_quantity.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_quantity.errors.required">Quantity is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>

  

            <div class="from-group ">
                <label for="product_price">Product Price:</label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="product_price" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_price.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_price.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_price.errors.required">Price is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        
        <div class="row">
             <div class="from-group col-4">
                <label for="product_image">Choose image file:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_price.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_image.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_image.errors.required">File is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="from-group col-4">
                <label for="produt_category">Product Category:</label>
                <select formControlName="product_category" class=“form-control” [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_category.errors }">
                    <option value="">Choose your category</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let category of Category" [ngValue]=category >{{category}}</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_category.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_category.errors.required">category is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group col-4">
                <label for="product_condition">Product Condition:</label>
                <select formControlName="product_condition" class=“form-control” [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.product_condition.errors }">
                    <option value="">Choose your condition</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let condition of Condition" [ngValue]=condition >{{condition}}</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.product_condition.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.product_condition.errors.required">condition is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <button class="submit-btn" ><span>Submit</span></button>
            </div>
        

        </form>
    </div>

    

</div>
```

this is service

```
  addProductFromAdmin(admin_id:string,product:any):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.http.post<boolean>(environment.apiUrl+'addProductFromAdmin/'+admin_id,product);
  }
```

Comment: this.productService.addProductFromAdmin share code of productService, Maybe your missing to define addProductFromAdmin

Comment: I did, this is service.

Comment: @hello Is that `productService` class is `@Injectable`?

Comment: oh yes, you right. I have @inject service.

Comment: @hello I think your `productService` is not initiated at all. Please check the code. If it is an @Injectable then you can use constructor to initiate it.

Comment: @SJNF yes, Thank You.